Seeking a high-performance C++ library for finite-state automata
I am looking for a high-performance C++ library similar to Java's dk.brics.automaton for working with finite-state automata. The library should be open-source and preferably free to use.
In addition to basic creation and manipulation of finite-state automata (DFA and NFA), I also require the following features:
Conversion of regular expressions to finite-state automata Performing various operations on finite-state automata, such as determinization, complement, intersection, union, etc. Mata (https://github.com/VeriFIT/mata/) might be an option, but its performance is lower compared to dk.brics.automaton.
Any suggestions or recommendations would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!
Mata (https://github.com/VeriFIT/mata/) , but its performance is lower compared to dk.brics.automaton.
